# Shell script to retrieve row value and store it in variable

Tags: sql, shell, unix

Is there any way **to retrieve a SQL query result** through shell script (i.e. sh). Suppose, select id from table; and result is id=10. Then I **should be able to store the result of ID into some variable var=10**. However I am not able to do what I want to do.
I am working on UNIX.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.  Instead try and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

#/bin/bash

var=` mysql -u root -pPassword databasename -e 'select id from table' `

echo $var